# Google plus sync execution script for simple web sites

Tags: html, google-plus

How is it possible to force the SCRIPTS of Google plus to make the call in a sync mode (in an HTML5 web app)? Even if it is called the simplest script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

This script introduces another script with the "ASYNC=""" attribute. So the execution of the second one is Asynchronous...

I need to have a SYNC execution to overcome a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring how assets load is not part of the public API. You're best bet would be to set an [onload callback](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#specifying_an_onload_callback).